# What does "Paid/Adjusted in 2023 for 2022" mean on a 1099-DIV?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, form-1099-div

On a 1099-DIV, what does this column heading mean?

Paid/Adjusted in 2023 for 2022

Does it refer to dividends that were earned (e.g. the record date came in 2022) but not paid?

Comment: what type of account is connected to the 1099?

Comment: @mshoran_psprep It is a brokerage account with dividends from stock. Nearly all of  the dividends are qualified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to moneys paid in 2022, initially characterized as dividends, and then in 2023 retroactively reclassified as something else (usually non-dividend distributions, i.e.: adjustments to basis). The amount adjusted should show up in a different box from the original amount. For example, if a non-dividend distribution was classified as a dividend and reported in box 1, after adjustment it would then be reported in box 3.